# 100% Height Section Depending On Screen?

Tags: css

I'm making a page with about 10 sections that a user can scroll through.

I need these sections to be full height, in other words, filling up the browser no matter the screen size or type.

The CSS for the sections looks like:

```
.scrollsections {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

The CSS for HTML and Body also looks like:

```
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

According to everything I could find, this should do the trick, but it is not.

Site is www.xenova.tv/site/plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vh property, which unfortunately has [partial browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).
 
If you need to support browsers that don't support it, you can try using a polyfill such as [this](https://github.com/saabi/vminpoly), or add fallback height values for other browsers.

For more information on using these units, you can read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) on css-tricks.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you should set height Property from window 
and in resize trigger call this
e.g :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).load(function () {
            setSize();
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            setSize();
        });
    });

    function setSize() {
        $("#div").height($(window).height() - 20);
    }
```